# Show content from pages based on Current Date

Tags: custom-post-types

[image]I am designing a site and trying to recreate this page structure https://www.britannica.com/on-this-day . For This I created a CPT named On-This-Day. Inside On this day post type there are two type of articles Parent is Day and month its child are the major events happend on that specific date. I completed this part but the only thing left is I want my on this day page to render the content from my CPT based on the current date. My staging site url https://wordpress-886233-3072476.cloudwaysapps.com/on-this-day/february-8/
https://wordpress-886233-3260398.cloudwaysapps.com/on-this-day/
And here are some Screenshots of everything. Any help is really needed as I am stuck.

Comment: Would it not have made more sense to use standard date archives and set the posts publish date to the date it was meant to represent? Then you'd get free listings, and you could use the standard date options in queries. Doing it the way you described means rebuilding all of that from scratch. Also your URLs don't work and the screenshots you mentioned are missing, there's also no code in your question

Comment: @TomJNowell sorry I updated the post, I did this to get the custom permalink structure and better organize my content. This site is going to be a blog so there will be thousands of articles and alot can happen on day and to add it we have to go though all the posts. But using CPT allows me to get the permalink structure as in my site and the ability to store this type of content here.

Comment: that's unfortunate, but also unnecessary, standard posts can have URLs that contain the date and they don't need parent posts with the year and month to do it. Querying your posts where the date is stored as the title of a parent post is going to be very difficult/awkward